# Python webscraper with Beautiful soup only returns one row of data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to coding and for a class project, we're supposed to build a webscraper using python and BeautifulSoup. Following some tutorials I've found online, I put together this code that seemingly works in general, but for the print(nick) command only returns the last row of the referenced table. Weirdly enough, the print(table) command is able to return all rows/all the table data.

One more issue the script has is that it can't return the "team" data which is stored differently in the HTML table:

[image]

I'm a beginner, so I'm having trouble understanding what's causing this issue.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.hltv.org/stats/players?startDate=2022-02-24&endDate=2023-02-24&matchType=Lan'

#empty array
player_list = []

#requesting and parsing the HTML file
response = requests.get(url)
#print(response.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

#selecting the table
table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'stats-table')
###print(table)

#storing all rows into one variable
for player_data in table.find_all('tbody'):
    rows = player_data.find_all('tr')

#looping through the HTML table to scrape the data
    for row in rows:
        nick = row.find_all('td')[0].text
        team = row.find_all('td')[1].text
        maps = row.find_all('td')[2].text
        rounds = row.find_all('td')[3].text
        kddiff = row.find_all('td')[4].text
        killdeath = row.find_all('td')[5].text
        rating = row.find_all('td')[6].text

print(nick)
print(team)
```

If anyone's able to help, please let me know!

Comment: Did you use ChatGPT to generate the code above?

Comment: No, I used this tutorial. https://www.scraperapi.com/blog/python-loop-through-html-table/

Comment: You're defining an empty list, but not using it. Also, how are you trying to surface the data? Print it one by one? Add it to a list and print the list? Add it to a table? Save it in some file form?

Comment: From the title it sounds like you are sent an array or list which you then either don't loop through, or you loop through and don't output each element from. If you don't loop through it, or you loop through it without outputting each tuple, then you will indeed just output one element when the process or loop is done.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus My next step would be to export the data to as .CSV. Just trying to understand this step-by-step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you output the last value stored in the nick variable, `print(nick)` must be added to the loop to output all the names. As for `print(team)`, there are several more tags in the 'td' tag referring to the names of the 'img' commands, you need to find them all, then iterate through the loop and return the entire name using `get()`, here is an example of an implementation with the output of these values:

```
#looping through the HTML table to scrape the data
    for row in rows:
        nick = row.find_all('td')[0].text
        team = [t.get('title') for t in row.find_all('td')[1].find_all('img')]
        maps = row.find_all('td')[2].text
        rounds = row.find_all('td')[3].text
        kddiff = row.find_all('td')[4].text
        killdeath = row.find_all('td')[5].text
        rating = row.find_all('td')[6].text
        print(team)
        print(nick)
```

Comment: Thank you, this has been super helpful. One issue that still comes up however is that 'team' returns all the teams a specific player has played for. Ideally, it would just return the team that the player is currently on. Any idea how to solve this? 

For the next step of this project, I wanted to export the data into a .CSV using the following code

`#creating a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(player_list)

#naming the columns
df.index = ['Player']

#exporting data into Excel
df.to_csv('PlayerData.csv')`

however I'm receiving a ValueError (expecting 144 elements, new values have 1)

Comment: To reitarate, the original problem has been solved using your solution.

Comment: To collect data about the current team, you need to collect links to the profile, follow them and collect the value of the current team. `nick = row.find_all('td')[0].find('a').get('href')
        stats_player = requests.get(f'https://www.hltv.org{nick}')
        stats_player_soup = BeautifulSoup(stats_player.text, 'html.parser')
        stats_player_team = stats_player_soup.find('div', class_ = 'summaryInfoContainer').find('a').text
        print(stats_player_team)`